# Dynamically expandable JVM stack

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

The [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2) indicates the JVM stack can be either fixed size or dynamically expandable.

The -Xss JVM option allow to set the fixed size and if I am right not setting this option is setting a default value (around 512-2048k), but how can tell the JVM to dynamically allocate its stack when needed?

If I cannot set a dynamical size option, will setting a large -Xss value (let's say 20M) actually allocate 20MB of memory for each thread in my JVM or is it dynamically allocated memory that will be limited to 20MB?

Comment: I'm not very satisfied by the answers to this question. On 64 bits architectures, is there a real penalty to allocate gigabytes to the stack?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The maximum stack size is the amount of *virtual address space* that gets allocated to the stack. Memory is only committed to the stack as required.

Note that on 32-bit systems, virtual address space is a relatively scarce resource. You get less (sometimes *much* less) than 4GB per process. With this in mind, a 20MB stack would limit the number of threads to anywhere between 75 and 175.

Comment: Meaning that for a given thread not using more than 1024k of stack, setting -Xss1024k or -Xss1024m will have exactly the same performance? A short limit whould only be a security for buggy recursive code?

Comment: How can you explain that in the [HotSpot FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html) (section "My application has a lot of threads and is running out of memory, why?") it is recommended to reduce the -Xss value to be able to run more threads when facing OutOfMemory?

Comment: @A21z If you use `-Xss1m` or `-Xss1g` will have much the same effect on a 64-bit JVM. On a 32-bit JVM you have a limited virtual address space to between 1.5 and 3.5 GB depending on the OS (regardless of how much memory you have)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding dynamic expansion, even though the specification may support it the implementation might not.

So, How to tell the JVM to dynamically allocate its stack when needed?

You Dont. You leave all settings as default and if the computation in a thread requires a larger stack than is permitted, the Java virtual machine throws a StackOverflowError.

This is your cue to use -Xss to explicitly increase memory allocation to new threads.

This does not affect the JVM Heap. [see -Xmx -Xms for setting heap size]

Also I must say, 20Mb seems slightly excessive per thread.

All depends on the size of your heap and the number of concurrent threads you would like to support.