# Does the "Xss" option for the Hotspot JVM set the "initial stack size" which is fixed or the "maximum stack size" upto which the stack can grow?

Tags: java, memory, stack-overflow, jvm-hotspot, stack-size

For the Hotspot JVM, does the **Xss** option set the **initial stack size** which is always fixed at this size? Or does it set the **maximum stack size** so that the stack starts with a lower size initially and can then grow up to a maximum size which is set?

This behaviour is pretty clear for the "heap size" where "Xms" sets the initial heap size and "Xmx" sets the maximum heap size. But the "Xss" option does not seem to be clear for me.

NOTE: I went through the post [Dynamically expandable JVM stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456720/dynamically-expandable-jvm-stack), but I could not get the clear answer from that post.

Answer (score 0):

`-Xss` sets the initial thread stack size (adjusted by OS specific algorithms).

E.g. take a look at the [linux implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/81d815b05abb/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp), line 4130-4151:

The `-Xss` value was put in variable `ThreadStackSize` by the launcher. After sanitizing and rounding it is stored via `JavaThread::set_stack_size_at_create` and will later be used to size the stack when a new Java thread is created.

Don't know if Hotspot implements dynamic expansion of thread stacks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Suppose my application process has 10 threads, 9 of them needing 128k and one of them needing 1024k. Ideally, 2176k (128k * 9 + 1024k) of stack memory would have sufficed for this application. Does setting Xss to 1024k reserve an initial and fixed stack memory of 10 MB (1024k * 10) when the threads start, when actually 2176k would have sufficed? So an additional 8064k memory is wasted since the same memory could have been used for other purposes like the heap?

Comment: @SanjayBhat yes that seems to be the sad consequence