# Java 17 stack size and actual memory consumption

Tags: java, jvm, java-17

Is there any real downside to allow for a VERY large stack on the JVM, like gigabytes?

In particular, with many threads, is this going to give troubles? if the stack space is not actually used, is there going to be more wasted memory in practice on the most used JVMs running on win/linux/mac?

For example, if I allocate 1GB for the stack, and I run 100 threads, but they do not actually fill up the stack space with actual data,
would running the program require 100GB of actual physical memory?

This question is strongly connected with this old one ([Dynamically expandable JVM stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456720/dynamically-expandable-jvm-stack)) that was asked 10 years ago when the Java environment was quite different.

Now near every Java program runs over a 64 bits architecture, and so much in JVM has overall improved.

Expansion:
I'm often running very complex recursive programs on large/deep data structures, and having to use free monads or other program transformations to use the heap instead of the stack is complex, slow and possibly pointless.
An alternative would be using Java looms fibers, but.. again, may be just allocating a duper stack is easier and faster.
I see why this is not done in C/C++, but under a VM this should be reasonable. Is it?

Comment: _"In particular, with many threads, is this going to give troubles?"_  It's not clear what you're asking.  There will be trouble if you exceed the physical available memory on your machine.

Comment: I wrote "if the stack space is not actually used," that is what I mean, I will edit to add an example.

Comment: Perhaps you should give an example of how you would set a large stack size.

Comment: Interesting question. I did a quick test with a real application (two or three dozen threads) and `-Xss1G` on Windows and it does indeed not seem to matter at all. But if you really use deep recursion a lot, it might become a problem if the stack memory is never given back (as long as the thread is alive).

Comment: did you mean that you fear that onece a stack acquires memory it never gives it back to the OS even if the stack has rolled back, or did you mean that my application may do a ton of recursion and then, deep deep in the recursion, a long lived loop? for the second one I think it would be ok (I'm actually using that memory), I'm worried about the first one.

Comment: If you ever encounter an endless recursion (which ends up in a StackOverflow) then you will face the downside, because it will take ages for the StackOverflow to reach it's limit. In general if you never encounter a StackOverflow in operation there is no need to increase the stack size.

Comment: @MarcoServetto the former: a thread may execute a method with deep recursion, followed by other actions not using the now-committed stack at all. Or even lots of threads running into this scenario.